# I need to reset my /.bash_profile to its default

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

Whenever I open the terminal, this error message pops up:

> -bash: /Users/j/.bash_profile: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token 'source'
>
> -bash: /Users/j/.bash_profile: line 2: `if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi source /Users/jackdavis/.bash_profile'

I was wondering how to reset the `/.bash_profile` so that this does not pop up when I open up terminal.

Comment: could you add the content of this file ? maybe the first 5 lines or so ?

Comment: On MacOS, the default value of this file is *for it not to exist at all*. (Default home directory contents live in `/System/Library/User Template/English.lproj`, for reference).

Comment: @MostafaHussein there are only two <br> if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi <br>
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi source /Users/jackd\
avis/.bash_profile

Comment: Also, StackOverflow is specifically for questions about software development. Inasmuch as this is an end-user support question, it's probably better fitted to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), [UNIX SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @jackd, ...if it's just two lines, then delete it. That, or add the missing semicolon or newline after the `fi`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for your help, I will also redirect any other support questions to any of those

Comment: @jackd Yes thats correct I have updated my answer.

Comment: The file you want to modify is `~/.bash_profile`.  WIthout the tilde, you are referring to a file in the root directory of your computer, which should not exist, or if it does, you should not have write access to.

Answer (score 1):

This line needs to modified from:

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi source
```

to

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

I think `source` should not be here

`source /Users/jackdavis/.bash_profile` this should be on a separate line

Comment: Good point, but one mystery remains: the `source` command apparently tries to source `~/.bash_profile` _itself_, which would result in an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would not delete it, but keep it for reference in case you have a path you need in the future.
You can run the command
mv ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile_backup

The system will still always have the generic /etc/profile so don't worry.

If you post the bash_profile I might be able to fix it with you.
After the new file is created check the old bash_profile to see if there are things you might need and copy them to your new bash_profile.

I noticed that your current user is 'j' whereas the user in the bash_profile is /Users/jackdavis

Comment: Yes that worked. Thank you so much. The formatting for the copy and paste of the error message was weird so I forgot to retype the user as jackdavis.